# Adding DIVs step-by-step...1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 16

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create div boxes step by step and animate them for several times when a button is pressed. I have a running code, and everything is going well. It goes right to the endhost, then it goes left again to its original place. This is mainly what I do, and also the demo is found here: http://jsfiddle.net/LSegC/1/

Now what I want to do is to increase the number of whole animated DIVs one-by-one (as it is now) up to 3 Divs, but then have exponential increase on the total number of DIVs. So the **total number** of animated DIVs will be like 1, 2, 3, and then 4, 8, 16, etc.

Remember, my problem is not with the *number* being shown inside the DIV, it's actually that *how many* DIVS are being created! So I want for instance 8 DIVs, numbered from 1 to 8 animated. Hope it is now clear.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("button").click(function() {

  var d = $(".t").fadeIn();
  var speed = +$("#number1").val();

  d.animate({left:'+=230px'}, speed);
  d.animate({left:'+=230px'}, speed);
  d.animate({top:'+=20px', backgroundColor: "#f09090", text:'12'}, speed/4, "swing", function() {
      $('.span', this).fadeOut(100, function() {
          $(this).text(function() {
              return 'a' + $(this).text().replace('a', '');
          }).fadeIn(100);
      });
  });
  d.delay(1000).animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed);
  d.animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed);
  d.fadeOut().promise().done(function() {
      d.last().after(function() {

          var top = +$(this).css('top').replace('px', ''),
              number = +$(this).data('number') + 1,
              $clone = $(this).clone();

          $clone.data('number', number).css('top', top + 20);
          $clone.find('.span').text(number);

          return $clone;
      });

      d.find('.span').text(function() {
          return $(this).text().replace('a', '');
      });
  })
```

});

Comment: Why are you doing this, this way? :s. This could be much simpler

Comment: ummm, how?! I tried to define a flag, and after that tried to double the number of 'new' to-be-added Divs. But my problem is with the exponential add!

Comment: Its really hard to understand your code, since you chained so many events together.

Comment: Well, you can forget about this code! you can just help me in how to exponentially create div!

Comment: is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/s7qKJ/2/?

Comment: You need to reset the height offset of the box so that it doesn't move increasingly lower on the screen after each run.

Comment: Heres another way to do animation with css keyframes: http://jsfiddle.net/3LMLN/

Comment: @stackErr For your first comment (http://jsfiddle.net/s7qKJ/2/): It just changes the number exponentially...e.g. I want to show 8 divs instead of 5; the numbers should still be 1 to 8!

Comment: @stackErr Regarding your second comment, that is doing the first animation, but the for the second and so on, nothing happens normally! It jumps from one side to another!

Comment: @Luxelin Later Later I will fix it...now fixing the logic is more important

Comment: @TinaJasmin I was just trying to show an example where you can achieve what you want with a lot less complex code.

Comment: @stackErr Well, I need to have the animation...that's a requirement

Comment: @stackErr Well, you know what? Let's focus on this: I want to create something like this: http://histrory.visualland.net/tcp_fast_recovery.html

Comment: @TinaJasmin do you want it to go forever? Or does it stop at 16 packets?

Comment: @stackErr Forever could be a plus..But let's assume at 16 DIVs it will stop. Just like the simulation I gave you the link above

Comment: Ok I recreated what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/54hqm/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Your code was too hard to manipulate as it was, I recreated the whole thing:
HTML:

```
<img id="streamline1" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/streamline-icon-set-free-pack/48/Streamline-04-48.png" />
<img id="LAN" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ecqlipse2/NETWORK%20-%20LAN.png" />
<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/streamline-icon-set-free-pack/48/Streamline-04-48.png" id="streamline" />
<div id="mid"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
<div>Speed (mS):
    <input value="500" id="speed" type="number" style="position: relative"></input>
    <button>Apply!</button>
    <!-- dynamic area -->
    <div class="packets"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var count = 0;
    var items = 0;
    var packetNumber = 0;
    var speed = 0;
    $("button").click(function () {

        if (count < 4) {
            items = items + 1;
            count++;
        } else {
            items = items * 2;
        }

        speed = $("#speed").val();
        createDivs(items);
        animateDivs();
    });

    function createDivs(divs) {
        packetNumber = 1;
        var left = 60;
        for (var i = 0; i < divs; i++) {
            var div = $("<div class='t'></div>");
            div.appendTo(".packets");
            $("<font class='span'>" + packetNumber + "</font>").appendTo(div);
            packetNumber++;
            div.css("left",left+"px");

            div.hide();
            left += 20;
        }
    }

    function animateDivs() {
        $(".t").each(function () {
            var packet = $(this);

            packet.show();

            packet.animate({
                left: '+=230px'
            }, speed);

            packet.animate({
                left: '+=230px'
            }, speed);

            packet.animate({
                top: '+=20px',
                backgroundColor: "#f09090",
                text: '12'
            }, speed / 4, "swing", function () {

                $('.span').fadeOut(100, function () {

                    $(this).text(function () {
                        return 'a' + $(this).text().replace('a', '');
                    }).fadeIn(100);

                });

            });
            packet.delay(1000).animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed);
            packet.animate({left:'-=230px'}, speed);
        }).promise().done(function(){
        $(".packets").empty();});

    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#bottom {
    border: 1px dashed gray;
    position: absolute;
    left: 55px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 30px;
    z-index=-1;
}
#mid {
    border: 1px dashed gray;
    position: absolute;
    left: 55px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 10px;
    z-index=-1;
}
.t {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: lightgreen
}
#streamline {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    right: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 548px;
}
#streamline1 {
    left: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
#LAN {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 275px;
    position: fixed;
}
.packets {
    display: inline;
}
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/54hqm/3/

Comment: I did the same; my problem is not with the number being shown inside the DIV, it's actually that how many DIVS are being created! So I want for instance 8 DIVS, numbered from 1 to 8 animated. Hope it is now clear.

Comment: Your solution is great. However, what I want to happen after each click, is basically to move each DIV one after another, as the animation shows, instead of moving the whole stack of DIVs at once.

Answer (score 0):

It was tough for me to follow the code also, but I cut it back quite a bit, came up with a "one-way" "empiric" approach. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LSegC/4/)

The speed can be adjusted by the change in the increment (inc), but there are a variety of methods that can be used.

Can you be more specific about what you mean by "exponential"? Do you mean an exponential speed increase across the div, or rather a speed increase until you get to 50%, then a decrement in speed.

JS

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var speed = 1000;
  var d = $('.mover');
  d.show();
  var inc = 1;
  for (var i=0; i<290; i=i+inc)
  {
   d.animate({   left: i,
               easing: 'linear'}, 1);
   if (inc < 11)
     {
      inc = inc + 1;
      } else {
      inc = inc - 1;
               }
   }
});
```

Comment: You can just animate with d3, which already has linear and exponential speed built in.

Comment: @TimSPQR: Thanks for sharing your code; but I'm not concerned with the speed. My problem is how to add DIVs. So first I want to add a single DIV, then 2 DIVs, ...

Comment: Then I'm unsure of exactly what you want. You want to start with one div at the beginning,  then after a period of time, add a div, then after a period of time add another div? etc. Or do you want one div to cross left to right, then another div to cross left to right until they all pile up at the end?

Comment: Well, I was thinking first add one DIV, then 2 DIVs, then 4 DIVs, etc

Comment: @TimSPQR Well, you know what? Let's focus on this: I want to create something like this: http://histrory.visualland.net/tcp_fast_recovery.html

Comment: Now I understand. It's an interesting project. I'll try to play with some ideas over the next few days.

Comment: @TimSPQR One of the members solved it. However, after each click, what I want is basically instead of moving the whole stack of DIVs, I want them to move one after another, as the animation shows.